# fill SQL empty database value with result from second table (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, so i'm not sure if i'm going about this a completely horrid way.
However, i'm basically trying to create a movie database for my room mates to show what content we have on our server and to easily check this out.

I have created a database that is automatically updated using the xml feed from our plex server, however there is one small bit that has been bugging me all night.

I'm trying to create a slider for recently added content, but when it comes to a "summary", films add there summaries to my "recent" table, where as tv episodes do not (not sure why plex's xml goes like this but im trying to work around it). the TV episodes have there summary in the "episodes" table.

What i'm trying to do is loop through the recent table and if the "recent"->"Desc" field is empty, pull content from "episodes"->"Desc" instead (matching by show title)

The code I have for this loop so far is:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","","","plex");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

                $recent = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM recent LIMIT 0, 6");
                $shows = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM shows");
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($recent))
                {
                    $art = $row['Art'];
                    $title = $row['Title'];
                    if (empty($row['Desc'])){
                        /* STUCK HERE*/
                    }
                    else {
                        $summary = $row['Desc'];
                    }
                    echo "<img src='$art.jpg' alt='$summary' title='$title' />";
                }
                mysqli_close($con);
        ?>
```

And my tables look like:

```
**********episodes**********************      **********recent*************
****************************************      *****************************
*id**eptitle**showtitle**desc*thumb*art*      *id**Title**Desc**thumb**art*
*  **       **         **    *     *   *      *  **     **    **     **   *
```

I will do my best to clarify on anything that isn't clear (it's late, you know :P)

Comment: Is the table `episodes` or `shows`? Your query reads `shows` but your description says otherwise.

Comment: And is there a relationship between these tables (is `recent.Title` the same as `episodes.showtitle`)?

Comment: Wow, I completely overlooked the table name difference. (ill change that in a sec, I want to use "episodes")
and yes recent.Title will be the same as episodes.showtitle :)

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to do this with a single query here is what you can do:

```
$recent = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT r.Art, r.Title, if(r.Desc is null or r.Desc = '', e.Desc, r.Desc) as `Desc` FROM recent r inner join episodes e on r.Title = e.showtitle LIMIT 0, 6");
```

You could then get rid of the second select statement altogether, and you PHP code within the while loop would be:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($recent))
{
    $art = $row['Art'];
    $title = $row['Title'];
    $summary = $row['Desc'];
    echo "<img src='$art.jpg' alt='$summary' title='$title' />";
}
```

Comment: Wow, that looks a lot cleaner!
I have just edited my code to yours however i now get a lovely:
:  mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given
for the While loop line (not sure why, based on what i can see)

Comment: @J3d-Design, the boolean is because the query failed.  I've updated the query, please try again.  Also, suggest executing this query in the db directly to verify the table names and column names are correct.

Comment: seems to have fixed the query, however is now not outputting anything on a print_r of $row.
Thanks for sticking with me on this so far :)

Comment: You mentioned `recent.Title` is same as `episodes.showtitle`, do both tables have matching `titles` and `showtitle`?

Comment: AHH, I just noticed it outputs a "season" number on the recent table. i will remove that from the database updater and try again ;)

Comment: OK, i have edited the database to ensure they are the same and it now outputs! Only problem being it only outputs the first item and no summary. and i think i know why on doing a print_r.. "[if(r.Desc is null or r.Desc = '', e.Desc, r.Desc)] => DESCRIPTION" is whats being output. but the description is there! :)

Comment: Try running the query in your mysql and verify the results.

Comment: Looks like it's giving the Desc column the name "if(r.Desc is null or r.Desc = '', e.Desc, r.Desc)" directly from the query. and only pulls in information relating to "dexter" which happens to be the most recent tv show in recently added (but not the most recent overall)

Comment: Updated query in the answer to add an alias `Desc` for the if.  For the most recent, you can add `order by id desc` before the `limit`.

Comment: looks like we're getting another sql query issue.
 near 'Desc FROM recent r inner join episodes e on r.Title = e.showtitle LIMIT 0, 6'
I think im going to call it a night and come back at it with a fresh head. Please do leave a further message to enlighten me when i do so! :) Thanks for all your help, i feel like i'm alot closer!

Comment: No wonder! that's a reserved word, wrap `Desc` with back ticks.  Updated answer.

Comment: Ok i changed that and the query works again :P thank you very much, but I think i have to get some sleep. (4.15am here!) I appreciate all your help. I would mark your answer up, however I "dont have enough rep" :(